# VBScript to Move files with particular extension

Tags: vbscript

I currently have a VBscript that scans a folder for files and moves the files to particular folders depending on key words in the file name.

I need currently the script only scans the one level (ie. doesn't scan recursively) and I need to to search all sub folders too.

Can someone give me a hand with this?

EDIT: Since writing this script I have realized that I need to have this only move files with particular extensions from a particular folder and sub folders to other directories based on the file name.
For example I need only .mp4 and .avi files to be moved.

Can someone help me with this please? I have tried multiple things but still can't get the recursive scanning and moving or the extension specific moving working.

Below is my current script.

```
'========================================================
' Script to Move Downloaded TV Shows and Movies to
' correct folders based on wildcards in File Name
'========================================================

On Error Resume Next

Dim sTorrents, sTV, sMovie, sFile, oFSO

' create the filesystem object
Set oFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create Log File
Set objLog = oFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\log.txt", 8, True)

' Set Variables
sTorrents = "C:\Temp\torrents\"
sTV = "C:\Temp\TV Shows\"
sMovie = "C:\Temp\Movies\"

' Scan each file in the folder
For Each sFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sTorrents).Files
' check if the file name contains TV Show Parameters
If InStr(1, sFile.Name, "hdtv", 1) OR InStr(1, sFile.Name, "s0", 1) <> 0 Then
    ' TV Show Detected - Move File
    objLog.WriteLine Now() & " - " & sFile.Name & " Detected as TV Show - Moving to " & sTV
    oFSO.MoveFile sTorrents & sFile.Name, sTV & sFile.Name
' Move all other Files to Movies Directory
Else objLog.WriteLine Now() & " - " & sFile.Name & " Detected as Movie - Moving to " & sMovie
    oFSO.MoveFile sTorrents & sFile.Name, sMovie & sFile.Name
End If

Next

If sTorrents.File.Count = 0 And sTorrents.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
    objLog.WriteLine Now() & " - There is nothing left to Process..."
    objLog.Close
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

```
Sub listfolders(startfolder)
Dim fs 
Dim fl1 
Dim fl2 

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fl1 = fs.GetFolder(startfolder)

    For Each fl2 In fl1.SubFolders
        Debug.Print fl2.Path

        ''process the files
        ProcessFiles fl2.Path 

        'Recursion: lists folders for each subfolder
        listfolders fl2.Path
    Next
End Sub

''Code copied from question
Sub ProcessFiles(sPath)
    ' Scan each file in the folder
    For Each sFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sPath).Files
        ' check if the file name contains TV Show Parameters
        If InStr(1, sFile.Name, "hdtv", 1) OR InStr(1, sFile.Name, "s0", 1) <> 0 Then
            ' TV Show Detected - Move File
            objLog.WriteLine Now() & " - " _
                  & sFile.Name & " Detected as TV Show - Moving to " & sTV
            oFSO.MoveFile sTorrents & sFile.Name, sTV & sFile.Name
        ' Move all other Files to Movies Directory
        Else 
            objLog.WriteLine Now() & " - " _
            & sFile.Name & " Detected as Movie - Moving to " & sMovie
            oFSO.MoveFile sTorrents & sFile.Name, sMovie & sFile.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to implement this into my script? I need to be able to run the above code on the subfolder items also.

Answer (score 0):

before the extension put a `*` that will find all files with that externsion.
Example: `oFSO.MoveFile (PATH\*.EXTERNSION)`

Answer (score 0):

here is a recusive function to list files in folders and sub folders
it's tested and working, but you'll probably need some adaptation to your own forkflow. And it's not the most optimized, but it's simple to read

```
Sub test()
  aFiles = F_ListFilesInDirAndSubDir("C:\foo\folder")
  'then, add some code to parse the array:
  For i = 0 to UBound(aFiles)
      'Move or not to move, that is what your code should tell
  Next
End Sub

Public Function F_ListFilesInDirAndSubDir(ByVal sDir)
    '===============================================================================
    'Get the list of files in a directory and in all its sub directories With the full path
    '===============================================================================
    Dim sChild      As String
    Dim aFolders    As Variant
    Dim aFiles      As Variant
    Dim aChildFiles As Variant
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    F_ListFilesInDirAndSubDir = aFiles
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fs.FolderExists(sDir) Then Exit Function

    'Get the files in the directory
    aFiles = F_ListFilesInDir(sDir)
    'Add the fullpath
    For i = 0 To UBound(aFiles)
        If aFiles(i) <> "" Then
            aFiles(i) = sDir & "\" & CStr(aFiles(i))
        End If
    Next

    'get the folders
    aFolders = F_ListFoldersInDir(sDir)

    'for each folders, push the files in the file list
    For i = 0 To UBound(aFolders)
        If aFolders(i) <> "" Then
            sChild = sDir & "\" & CStr(aFolders(i))
            'Recursive call on each folders
            aChildFiles = F_ListFilesInDirAndSubDir(sChild)
            'Push new items
            For j = 0 To UBound(aChildFiles)
                If aChildFiles(j) <> "" Then
                    ReDim Preserve aFiles(UBound(aFiles) + 1)
                    aFiles(UBound(aFiles)) = aChildFiles(j)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    F_ListFilesInDirAndSubDir = aFiles
End Function

Public Function F_ListFilesInDir(ByVal sDir)
    '===============================================================================
    'Get the list of files in a directory
    '===============================================================================
    Dim aList     As Variant
    Dim i         As Long
    Dim iChild    As Long
    Dim oFile
    Dim oFolder
    Dim oChildren
    ReDim aList(0)
    F_ListFilesInDir = aList

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not fs.FolderExists(sDir) Then Exit Function

    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(sDir)
    Set oChildren = oFolder.Files

    iChild = CDbl(oChildren.Count) - 1
    If iChild = -1 Then Exit Function

    ReDim aList(iChild)
    i = 0
    For Each oFile In oChildren
        aList(i) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    F_ListFilesInDir = aList
End Function

Public Function F_ListFoldersInDir(ByVal sDir As String) As Variant
    '===============================================================================
    'Get the list of folders in a directory
    '===============================================================================
    Dim aList     As Variant
    Dim i         As Long
    Dim oDir
    Dim oFolder
    Dim oChildren
    ReDim aList(0)

    F_ListFoldersInDir = aList

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fs.FolderExists(sDir) Then Exit Function

    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(sDir)
    Set oChildren = oFolder.SubFolders

    If oChildren.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    ReDim aList(oChildren.Count - 1)
    i = 0
    For Each oDir In oChildren
        aList(i) = oDir.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    F_ListFoldersInDir = aList
End Function
```