# move all xlsx files from directory to another using excel 2010 vba

Tags: excel, vba

In the `FromPath` there are 4 `xlsx` files that I would like to move to the variable `MyDirectory`. Currently the `vba` runs but when it gets to this point the files remain in the temp directory (FromPath) and do not get moved and I am not sure why. Thank you :).

**vba**

```
'TRANSFER FROM TEMP '
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String

FromPath = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\*.xlsx"
ToPath = "MyDirectory"


If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
    FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
End If

If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
    ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
```

**edit**

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim MyBarCode   As String      ' Enter Barcode
Dim MyScan      As String      ' Enter ScanDate
Dim MyDirectory As String

'GET USER INPUT '
Line1:
MyBarCode = Application.InputBox("Please enter the last 5 digits of the barcode", "Bar Code", Type:=2)

If MyBarCode = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
Do
    MyScan = Application.InputBox("Please enter scan date", "Scan Date", Date - 1, Type:=2)
    If MyScan = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
    If IsDate(MyScan) Then Exit Do
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid date format. ", vbExclamation, "Invalid Date Entry"
Loop

'CREATE NEXUS DIRECTORY AND VERIFY FOLDER '
MyDirectory = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy") & "\"
If Dir(MyDirectory, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir MyDirectory
Else
    MsgBox ("Already exsists! Please enter again")
    GoTo Line1
End If

' TRANSFER FILES '
 Dim MyFile As String

MyFile = Dir("C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\*.xlsx")

Do Until MyFile = ""

Name "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\*.xlsx" & MyFile As "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\" & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy") & MyFile

MyFile = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the topath need to be more explicit? C:\Users\Christophe\Desktop\MyDirectory\ you're also not checking if the MyDirectory folder exists...

Comment: `MyDirectory` is created in a step prior by user input.... I will try making the ToPath more explicit.  Thank you :).

Comment: `CopyFolder` doesn't accept a file mask (`*.xlsx`). It copies entire folders, not individual files, and it doesn't move (copy to a new destination and delete from the old), it **copies**. (That's why it's named **Copy**Folder.) See the code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12593730/62576) - the question asks about recursively moving files from multiple folders, but it has code for **moving** files rather than just copying them.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241927/copying-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-vba

Comment: I added an edit in which the user enters a # and that is stored as a variable and then the user enters a date which is also stored as a variable.  In the `transfer files` section all the xlsx files are supposed to be sent to those variables, but I am getting a bad file name error.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Have code that finds all xlsx files in a folder for other purposes, runs all the files through a for/next loop and finds those with .xlsx at the end, this will be really slow and inefficent if you've got millions of files to sort through.

```
Dim f As Object, fso As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.getfolder(Folder).Files
    If Left(f.Name, Len(ContractNumber)) = ContractNumber And Right(f.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Then
        f.CopyFile Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    End If
Next
```